# 2D array of object C#

Tags: c#, arrays, class, object, multidimensional-array

I know, this question may seems asked a lot, but still, I'm not able to solve it using the solution that people gives. So, I'm also having the exception "System.NullReferenceException : 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'" while trying to use an 2D array of object. So here's the not working code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace Console_multi_fonctionnelle_basique
    {
        partial class Program
        {
             public class SudokuSolver
             {
                 //Initialisation code
                 public SudokuSolver()
                 {
                     GridValue[,] SudokuGrid = new GridValue[9, 9];
                     SudokuDisplay(SudokuGrid);
                     Console.ReadKey();
                }
                //Store values for every slot
                class GridValue
                {
                    public bool CanBe1 { get; set; } = false;
                    public bool CanBe2 { get; set; } = false;
                    public bool CanBe3 { get; set; } = false;
                    public bool CanBe4 { get; set; } = false;
                    public bool CanBe5 { get; set; } = false;
                    public bool CanBe6 { get; set; } = false;
                    public bool CanBe7 { get; set; } = false;
                    public bool CanBe8 { get; set; } = false;
                    public bool CanBe9 { get; set; } = false;
                    public bool AlreadySolved { get; set; } = false;
                    public int Value { get; set; } = 0;
                }
                //Display the grid
                void SudokuDisplay(GridValue[,] Sudoku)
                {
                    Sudoku[1, 1].Value = 1;
                    Sudoku[1, 2].Value = 2;
                    Console.WriteLine(Sudoku[0, 0].Value + Sudoku[1,0].Value);
                }
                //To Do
                //Ask the values for every slot
                //Verify if the slot can contain a number
                //Choose the most appropriated number for the slot
                //End the program after user pressing an key
            }
        }
    }
```

So, like you can see, I want to use an 2D array of "GridValue" class of the size 9x9, so that every "Grid slot" have their own variable for later solving the sudoku. But the program is looking like not understanding that my Array contains "GridValue" objects so he seems not to understand that every Array value contain multiple variable... So the result I would like is that I can define variable to one of the objects in the Array without getting an exception.

Comment: please add the outer code, one thing for sure ll 2-3 of your constructor have to be removed and move to the outer code

Comment: Understand that (unlike intrinsic types such as `int` and `string`), class instances need to be initialized with `new` keyword. `GridValue[,] SudokuGrid = new GridValue[9, 9];` will simply allocate a two-dimensional array for you, whose all elements will be uninitialized. You need to do something like `SudokuGrid[0, 0] = new GridValue()` for every element of your grid.

Comment: Arrays are zero based in c#.  The first element is Sudoku[0,0] not Sudoku[1,1].  You aren't setting [0,0], so it is still null, but you are trying to access it when you write the value.

Comment: To clarify dotNET's answer even further: for uninitialized values the default value is used. The default of int is 0, the default of a string is null, the default for any class is also null.=> As you try to access a uninitialized value at `Sudoku[0,0].Value` which has the default value for classes, `null`, it returns a NullReferenceException.

Comment: `GridValue[,] SudokuGrid = new GridValue[9, 9];` initializes the array but does not initialize the elements of the array. So when you try to access the elements of the array you get null. You need to initialize the elements of the array before you can set their properties.

Comment: You will save **a lot** of typing when you make your bools a single `public List<int> PossibleValues = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9  };` and then `.Remove()` numbers from the list when you know it's not possible.

Comment: To answer nvoigt, I've noted it on my code so I'll try using it when time to code it will come...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this example helps you to understand OOP. Welcome to the community!

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            SudokuSolver sudokuSolver = new SudokuSolver(9, 9);

            sudokuSolver.DisplayGrid();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    } 


    public class SudokuSolver
    {
        //Store every values needed for every "slot"
        public class GridValue
        {
            public bool CanBe1 { get; set; } = false;
            public bool CanBe2 { get; set; } = false;
            public bool CanBe3 { get; set; } = false;
            public bool CanBe4 { get; set; } = false;
            public bool CanBe5 { get; set; } = false;
            public bool CanBe6 { get; set; } = false;
            public bool CanBe7 { get; set; } = false;
            public bool CanBe8 { get; set; } = false;
            public bool CanBe9 { get; set; } = false;
            public bool AlreadySolved { get; set; } = false;
            public int Value { get; set; } = 0;
        }

        public GridValue[,] SudokuGrid { get; }

        //Code d'initialisation
        public SudokuSolver(int x, int y)
        { 
            // only initialize in the constructor, no calls
            SudokuGrid = new GridValue[x, y]; // the array exists now in mem, but each entry is pointing to null
            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
                {
                    SudokuGrid[i, j] = new GridValue();
                }
            }
        }



        //Display the grid => then name it that way!
        public void DisplayGrid()
        {
            SudokuGrid[1, 1].Value = 1;
            SudokuGrid[1, 2].Value = 2;
            Console.WriteLine(SudokuGrid[0, 0].Value + SudokuGrid[1, 0].Value);
        }


     }

}
```

Comment: if everything is alright and you think this is the right answer please kindly mark it so in SO

Answer (score 0):

You have created an empty array, so when you try to access an element, an exception is thrown. 
Initialize the elements of your array and you should be ok.

```
public class SudokuSolver
{
    //Initialisation code
    public SudokuSolver()
    {
        GridValue[,] SudokuGrid = new GridValue[9, 9];

    //###################

        for (int r=0; r < 9; r++) 
        { 
            for (int c = 0; c < 9; c++) 
            { 
                SudokuGrid[r, c] = new GridValue(); 
            } 
        }

    //###################

        SudokuDisplay(SudokuGrid);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    //Store values for every slot
    class GridValue
    {
        public bool CanBe1 { get; set; } = false;
        public bool CanBe2 { get; set; } = false;
        public bool CanBe3 { get; set; } = false;
        public bool CanBe4 { get; set; } = false;
        public bool CanBe5 { get; set; } = false;
        public bool CanBe6 { get; set; } = false;
        public bool CanBe7 { get; set; } = false;
        public bool CanBe8 { get; set; } = false;
        public bool CanBe9 { get; set; } = false;
        public bool AlreadySolved { get; set; } = false;
        public int Value { get; set; } = 0;
    }
    //Display the grid
    void SudokuDisplay(GridValue[,] Sudoku)
    {
        Sudoku[1, 1].Value = 1;
        Sudoku[1, 2].Value = 2;
        Console.WriteLine(Sudoku[0, 0].Value + Sudoku[1, 0].Value);
    }
    //To Do
    //Ask the values for every slot
    //Verify if the slot can contain a number
    //Choose the most appropriated number for the slot
    //End the program after user pressing an key
}
```